# Clickable image that scales

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that has a mural as a background. When you click on certain parts of the mural, different things will happen.

To account for different browser / screen / device sizes, the mural is taller than it is wide.  So I am setting the image to always be the width of the browser. Since there will be clickable elements everywhere on the mural, I will need to vertically scroll.

I have tried numerous different css styles and I can get the image to scale horizontally, but it never allows me to scroll vertically to accommodate for the image size. Once I have the image scaling, I can being to implement the clickable elements based off of the image size / %.

Does anyone have any suggestions or can point me in the right direction?

*EDIT
Sorry I did not put the css I am currently using, I was a bit tired when I made this.

```
html {
    background-image:url('1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:absolute;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 0):

```
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover, .focus { transform: scale(1.1); }
```

***Or***

```
$('.grow').on('click',function(){
   $(this).css({
          'transition': 'all .2s ease-in-out',
          'transform': 'scale(1.1)'
    });
});
```